# Apple product warranty information using script

Tags: macos, shell, scripting

i was trying write a script which will in turn give me warranty expiration details of my apple product(OS X devices).

I found some old scripts written in shell as well as python in github which are making use of old link  https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do?sn="serial number".

But recently apple has taken down that link and added below mentioned link for getting all the warranty related information.
https://checkcoverage.apple.com/in/en/?sn="serial number".

problem with new link is that they have introduced "CAPTCHA" for querying warranty information, when i use the link using curl it results in some bad data because of it.

is there any way to bypass this captcha or any alternative way to get the information would be of great help.

Mainly i am looking for solution in shell script.

Ex :https://github.com/rustymyers/warranty

Note: i found some python script which make use of manufacturing date to confirm warranty but it is based on assumption and it also won't yield exact expiration date.